# Removing or hiding the Blog Posts and Popular Post widgets from Blogger

Tags: widget, blogger

Been going round in circles on this - I'm building a simple blog of my various art videos, music etc. SO I want more of a website and less of a blog so consequently I want to hide the Blog Posts and Popular Post widgets from the landing page.

I'm using the contempo blogger theme. By default the Blog Posts and Popular Posts widgets are non removable but you can go into theme - edit html and change locked from true to false and indeed visible from true to false. Click save and in layout it is all looking good but as soon as you load the blog back they come. Something is clearly reloading them - any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a different landing home page then use the conditional tag.

<b:if cond=’data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl’>

Your content here

</b:if>

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, based on Sulabh Shresha's answer.

- Template / edit html
- at the bottom, add this:

> ```
> <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
>     <!-- this script hides the main widget on the home page-->  
>     <script type="text/javascript">       
>     document.getElementById('Blog1).setAttribute('style','display:none;')  
>     </script>  
> </b:if>
> ```

- you can tweak the script to set custom HTML content for the Blog1 div, or its contents, instead of hiding it. So, something like this:

> ```
> document.querySelectorAll('.no-posts-message').forEach(
>     element =>  { element.innerHTML=`<h1>site under construction…</h1>` })
> ```